# Colocar JS só em uma div

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, tenho uma `div` que preciso que ela tenha uma versão menos atualizada do *js*.

Minha página está com o *Bootstrap 4.1* e preciso rodar o *jquery 2.2.3* na div, onde a versão mais atualizada *(3.2.1)* faz com que o conteúdo pisque e não é exibido corretamente.

Comment: Vc por acaso está usando a versão jquery-3.2.1.slim.js ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim você pode usar várias versões na mesma página.  O `jquery` permite isso usando uma função chamada `noConflict`. No seu caso ficaria assim para carregar os scripts na página:

```
 <script src="jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="jquery/2.2.3/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
```

Ao usar `$()` estará usando a versão 3.2.1, ao usar `$j()` estará usando a versão 2.2.3.

Assim, tudo que for relacionado aquela div em particular, use `$j`, que pode ser renomeado pra outra coisa que você preferir, como `$j223` por exemplo, e colocar corretamente os nomes dos arquivos na tag `script`.

Aqui a documentação: [jquery.noconflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: Aí a declaração do script 2.2.3, eu coloco dentro da div?

Comment: Se tiver script dentro da div pode declarar lá dentro, e os scripts relacionados à div precisam ser mudados... por exemplo se na div tivesse um id "divX", precisaria mudar pra `$j('#divX')`

Comment: Deu certinho aqui, muito obrigado!